# Is it lawful,for the Noahide Laws, the thesis of Gentiles Christians according to whom Jesus has a divine nature but he is subordinate to God?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, theology, christianity, noachide-laws

I am not a christian but I am an Italian noahide, therefore I do not believe in the divinity and messianicity of Jesus the Nazarene.

I clarify that my question, being relevant to the application of the Noahide Laws, does not concern Christians of Jewish ethnicity, who are obviously subjected to the Halachot  established for all the Israelites.

Almost all   Christians adhere to the so-called trinitarian creed, according to which God is one but at the same time is "composed" of three "persons" ( Father, Son and  Holy Spirit). This conception , for a significant and probably majority part of the Jewish tradition,is of an idolatrous nature.

However, there is a small minority of Christians who, on the basis of significant passages from the New Testament, reject the concept of trinity, denying that the Holy Spirit has an autonomous existence, and developing a particular conception of Jesus the Nazarene.

They indeed support a "high" christology,  but  affirm that Jesus is not  God ,and this on the basis of the following reasons:

- Jesus shares only a part of the substance of God, since the Nazarene is not the incarnation of HaShem but only of His "Logos";
- Jesus was "generated" by God, therefore he cannot be coeternal to the Creator;
- Last and most important consideration, Jesus is subordinated and subjected to the will of HaShem, as explicitly attested by not a few passages of the books of the New Testament.

As I said earlier, I'm noahide and not christian,but I would like to know if the position of these "anti-trinitarian" Gentiles Christians can be compatible with  the Noahide Laws as regards the prohibition of idolatry.

Comment: The extent to which Noahides are supposed to create their own religions gets debated back and forth. Accepting a non-prophet as a prophet or some sort of intermediary to the divine would appear to be incompatible with proper conduct for Bnei Noach, however

Comment: +1 Not that I have an answer but - I believe ancient pagan religions generally had a hierarchy of gods and demigods, with some of the gods begetting other gods.  I think the main idea of *avoda zara* (idolatry) is *serving* something/someone other than G-d.